# Traffic (views, visits) is not correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-analytics

In the [site analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics), [privileged users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) can monitor some things like the total traffic on the site. However, it seems to be broken at the moment, all figures are almost zero. This is how it looks for Meta Stack Exchange (other sites show similar pictures):

[image]

Comment: It is not all 0, for example on 2018-04-07 there were 41 page views, 35 visits and 1 new visit ... maybe MSE got the traffic stats of Health.se?

Comment: @rene this is just sick!

Comment: The same is on [Ukrainian Language](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) — since the 7th of April `new visits` are zero, while `visits` and `page views` are very small.

Comment: Same at [gis.se].

Comment: is this effecting Area51 stats too?

Comment: @NogShine yes it is! On [Ukrainian Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language) it went from 1250 a couple of days ago to 300 today!!! And I don't see admins reacting in any way!

Comment: @P.Vovk Yes, looks like it. I reported a [bug for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/357396) separately.

Comment: @NogShine well done, tnx.

Comment: We're investigating, we've had a number of large changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure, looks like we missed some bits...

Comment: Aviation got the weirdest graph: all 0ed out except for the week 6-12.04.

Comment: @Federico, it's not only Aviation; it seems to occur on all sites. At least Ukrainian language **showed a graph exactly like in the bug-report** few days ago (i.e. everything fine before 2018-04-06, low numbers after 2018-04-07), but now it **shows a graph similar to what you said about Aviation** (i.e. zeros before 2018-04-05, valid values for 2018-04-06..2018-04-11, very low values after 2018-04-12). **Should we update the bug-report with a new graph?**

Comment: When doing a site search, “Area 51” comes back with no results. How are people supposed to find it? I’ve only ever been able to find it because someone posted the link in a comment. Area 51 needs to be more accessible  which is partly why traffic analytics are dismal.

Comment: @M.Mat this is not about the traffic to Area 51 *itself*. Area 51 shows traffic to beta sites like [chess.se] and [astronomy.se], which you should be able to find via e.g. https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: Indeed Glorfindel, regardless, there needs to be an easier, user friendly war to GET THERE.

Comment: [Related report on PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16272/has-anybody-used-ppcg-se-before-april-5th)

Comment: Related post on [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/576/77)

Comment: This is quite clearly a [network-wide issue](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Comment: @rene Just pointing out that Health.SE's visits were and are better than that - although Area51 reports 1 visit/day now...

Comment: @DeanWard any update?

Comment: @Pandya so far as I'm aware this was fixed shortly after it was reported and after spot checking some sites this appears to be working fine? Are you still seeing issues?

Comment: @DeanWard E.g [Area51 pages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) still didn't count visits per day.

Comment: @Pandya ah, ok, lemme take a look

Comment: @DeanWard, the same is true for [Sports SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports). Visits per day is 0. Btw are the other 4 statistics shown correctly?

Comment: @gdrt this is now fixed, apologies for the delay

Comment: @Pandya all area51 pages now show the correct visits

Comment: @DeanWard thanks for fixing this. Time for a [status-completed] and an optional wrap up answer which I can accept?

Comment: @Dean, thanks but note that the homepages of beta sites still don't show the visits per day stats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apologies for the slow response here in completely resolving the issue. We made major changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure a few months back and completely missed that the same GA properties were used to drive the metrics behind Area51 stats and overall site analytics.

When we finally made the cut over to our new GA properties it coincided with the final couple of sprints before launching Teams so my time (and DAG's time) was completely tied up elsewhere.

But, enough excuses; Area51 and the main sites all reflect reality. So I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Thanks for the heads up

Comment: The homepages of beta sites still don't show the visits per day stats.

Comment: That's a [separate issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310112/can-we-hide-the-visitor-stats-until-theyre-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1), I think that temporary change can be undone.

Comment: @Glorfindel, opened a new [ticket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311997/unhide-visitors-per-day-stats-on-beta-sites-homepages).

Comment: There is a [bug reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312425/312043) related to this same issue.

Answer (score 30):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1007414_308966) is from one of our Developers:

> We're investigating, we've had a number of large changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure, looks like we missed some bits...

Comment: So, is this the reason for the mismatch of stats on Area51, Stack Exchange site also?

Comment: @NogShine Yes..

Comment: So should I close the related question as duplicate or should I wait till this gets a [tag:status-completed] ?

Comment: @NogShine It's best to close duplicates so not to split the status / updates / conversation.

Comment: It wasn't clear that this question was about Area 51 too. Edited it.

Comment: Seeing as it seems to be taking a little while to get this sorted, could I suggest temporarily changing the site stats widgets to point to 'last known good' data? It doesn't look very good to potential new users when beta sites proclaim '2 visitors/day' on their front page....

Comment: @Robert Just curious, don't you check how things work after making "large changes to infrastructure"? Sounds basic to me. Just saying, since it could save those 10 days it took you (the team, not you personally) to spot this bug report and start investigating, and all it takes to spot the bug is visiting one of the sites analytics page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard A51 is pretty much ignored most of the time. Also, I'm starting to get the sense that, due to the large active user base, there's an assumption that these things will be caught by the community sooner or later.

Comment: @ItamarG3 not talking about A51, well aware it's "ignored", as you said... this bug affects all sites. Robert happens to be the "boss" of Area 51 hence I guess many see him as linked only to that site, but he's also an ordinary CM, who sometimes post "general" replies, not related only to Area 51. :-)

Comment: I agree with @topomorto: people may think that is not useful at all to ask a question on a site with 3 visitors/day.

Comment: Is it time for a ~3 week update on this bug?

Comment: @hazzey I just checked this morning and it’s in progress;  high on whatever fast-track queue that gets this done sooner rather than later

Comment: I notice the visitors / day section is gone from some of the pages, which seems like a good temporary solution - thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino exactly one month later, any update? I understand Area 51 is very low in the development team priority list, and accept it, but still hope they can fix something like that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, unfortunately bug handling is a bit of black box to me. I inquired and escalated this a few times, but I don't know what the process/plan is beyond that.

Comment: @RobertCartaino well... the best of luck getting this fixed. :-)

Answer (score 13):

This is also affecting the Traffic Sources panel, which (on Physics, at least) isn't displaying any data at all:

> [image]

For comparison, this is what the traffic looks like on the history page:

> [image]

Comment: On Mi Yodeya, page views were previously normal until the drop in early April, and are now showing near-zero.  We, too, have the brief spike you have here, but only for the one stat.  See screen shots in [this duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309087/162102).

Comment: Same graph for Ask Ubuntu, a flat zero line outside the range from 5th to 12th April. In between there are numbers in the range of roughly 200k-900k.

Comment: On RPG.SE, traffic is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

- The visits/day seems to be realistic [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), for example 340 visits/day for quantum computing.
- It seems to be the Area 51 pages that are reporting near 0 visits, for example [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing).
- Google Analytics seems to be reporting realistic numbers, Area 51 is just not getting them (but [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)) is. Should not take long to fix.

Comment: Reproduced. Analytics page stats are in sync with Stack Exchange stats. The problem is only on Area51 now.