# Traffic isn't updated correctly on Area51

Tags: bug, area-51, site-visits

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) shows statistics for all the beta sites. It shows questions per day, percentage of answers etc.,  The statistics for visitors per day is not updated correctly on Area 51.

[image: Mythology area51 beta stats]

Above are the stats for [mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) If we see the stats on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), the stats for visitors per day are different. These stats are also shown on their home page also shows difference.

[image: mythology stats on homepage]

This difference is seen in almost all the beta sites.

It might be related to [the bug reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/357396) a few days ago about inconsistency of Google Analytics.

Update on 16/04/2018: [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) also shows wrong stats now.

Comment: the same goes for Ukrainian Language.

Comment: What is the reason to think that the problem with Area51 stats has different cause than the similar problem with individual sites stats? VTC/duplicate.

Comment: @bytebuster I would counter question you why it is the same. We don't know whether it is the same reason area51 stats are not updated. That is google analytics and this is area51. This is a bug. They are different ones.  Even if it is the same reason, I still see the problem with stats. So, we have to wait for a dev's response and solution.

Comment: Similar question on [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26161/is-there-some-information-about-the-beta-site-statistics) (but seems abandoned and no answer yet).

Comment: @HTTPS If it works normally, they show similar stats shown on SE website, but now, there is a problem about traffic.

Comment: [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51#comment1020383_308966).