# Why did the Area 51 statistics on number of visits per day drop extremely down for Beta sites?

Tags: bug, area-51, statistics, beta-sites

Recently, the number of visits per day on Beta sites dropped extremely down from thousands to units. Here are examples from [Sports SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) and [Chess SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551/chess). Is it a bug?

It seems like the values are missing the last three digits.

Comment: Here's the exact duplicate for Area 51 [Traffic isn't updated correctly on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/357396). we still don't know if bug for Site Analytics is the same cause for Area 51. It is possible though.

Comment: @Nog, please flag it.

Comment: No need of a flag again. I just posted the exact duplicate to let you know.