# Zero visitors? What happened to site analytics about a week ago?

Tags: bug, analytics

This is the views section of the site analytics visible to 25k users on one of my sites:

[image: graph showing drop to 0 visits for last week]

That's, uh, not correct.  Our site has had its usual activity level during this time.  I checked a couple other sites, and the pattern is consistent.  This looks like a problem in the analytics data that's coming in; did Google change their API?

**Update:** Same site a week later; note that in addition to the brief spike of accuracy, page views have dropped to (near-)zero for the whole period, unlike the earlier report.  (I know this question has been closed as a dupe, but I thought having the two screen shots together might help somebody.)

[image: page views that were previously normal are now zero-ish]

Comment: Yes, good catch. The same thing happened on cseducators.

Comment: @BenI. I think it probably happened everywhere, but I don't have the rep to check every site. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's the implication. Now we're just waiting to hear back from the CMs

Comment: JFYI: They're not zero, they're small numbers. If you set starting date as ≥2018-04-07, you'll see them (they're just too small comparing to the numbers of the previous days). At least at our site.