# Can we hide the visitor stats until they're fixed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta-sites, homepage

As detailed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) there is currently a network-wide issue impacting the visitor, views and visits statistics resulting mostly in zero amounts. Since this doesn't seem to have a quick fix—it's been a month—I'd prefer to have the stat hidden for now on the front page of the beta sites.

[image: Example: IoT frontpage when logged out]

Stack Exchange beta sites—especially the small ones—are still in the community ramp up phase. I can't quantify it but to be honest a *zero visitors per day* stat that's flung into a potential new users face is most likely not helping.

*Thus, please hide that stat on the front page until you fixed it and it returns to real values.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good idea! As of a few minutes ago that metric is hidden on all beta sites, until we fix the underlying issue:

[image: no visitors/day metric here!]

Comment: Can we do the same tweak on area51 ? as I think it's fixed at 50%, check there http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things