# Unhide visitors per day stats on beta sites' homepages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta-sites, homepage

Now that the issue with visitors per day is [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989/284747), could you please [unhide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310112/can-we-hide-the-visitor-stats-until-theyre-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1) the stats on the beta sites' homepages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The visitor stats will be back with the next prod build.