# What happened to the visits/day property on the "All Sites" page on stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, statistics

On stackexchange.com, the list of [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) contains several stats for every network site.  One of them was visits/day, but this has disappeared.

For an old screenshot where visits/day was included, see [the screenshot in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136299/172266) for an example.

What happened to the visits/day statistic?  Was it removed on purpose, or is this a bug/omission?

Comment: Good question! Maybe removed as part of the "fix" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310112/can-we-hide-the-visitor-stats-until-theyre-fixed) and they forgot to put it back when the actual bug was fixed. (bug causing it to always be 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was removed with the rest of the traffic data, as described in [A: Can we have a little notice letting people know that analytics changed after May 10, 2022?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392979/323179):

> We have removed Universal Analytics data throughout our sites because of the inaccuracy and eventual lack of support from Google.