# What constitutes a "visit/day" on Area 51, and is it broken?

Tags: discussion, bug, area-51, beta-sites

I am an active user of the [Latin Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com). Just now, out of curiosity, I visited [its page on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409?page=4&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top) to see how well the site was meeting the requirements needed for full graduation from beta. I was surprised, however, to see the *visits/day* metric sitting at 0. Screenshot:

[image: This can't be right...]

Initially, I thought that it was a simple error (cache fetching error, etc.), so I refreshed the page, but to no avail. The *visits/day* remained squarely at zero.

Upon further investigation, I discovered that there are *many* beta Stack Exchange site pages on Area 51, all with their *visits/day* metric at zero:

- [Quantum Computing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing)
- [Stellar](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115647/stellar)
- [Iota](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110603/iota)
- [Augur](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur)
- [Computer Science Educators](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)
- [DevOps](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops)
- [Ukranian Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language)
- [Mythology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology)
- [Open Source](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source)
- [Portuguese Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language)
- [Hardware Recommendations](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations)
- [Language Learning](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)
- [Retrocomputing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing)
- [Korean Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language)
- [Esperanto Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95499/esperanto-language)
- [Literature](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature)
- [Vegetarianism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/vegetarianism)
- [Ebooks](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks)
- [Beer, Wine and Spirits](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48905/beer-wine-and-spirits)
- [Expatriates](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates)
- [Mathematics Educators](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators)
- [Earth Science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science)
- [Craft CMS](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/69388/craft-cms)
- [Hinduism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism)
- [Moderators](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators)
- [History of Science and Mathematics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics)
- [Economics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics)
- [Lifehacks](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks)
- [Engineering](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering)
- [Music Fans](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans)
- [Woodworking](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61927/woodworking)
- [CiviCRM](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm)

And these are just from the first page alone (50 per page). Almost every single Beta page on the second page exhibited the same property, *visits/day* at 0. Interestingly though, there are a few pages with *visits/day* of 1 or 2, but neither of those seem any more correct than 0.

What's going on here? What exactly constitutes a *visit/day* on Area 51? Is the metric broken?

Comment: @Catija No - the analytics pages have been fixed AFAIK ([backed up by others as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51#comment1015199_310735)). Area51 is still broken.

Comment: Really? Closing this question as a duplicate despite the fact that the issue has been brought up previously and not been addressed? Sheesh.

Comment: The other one isn't marked as status completed, which means it's already on their list of bugs to squash. Having a second open bug report adds another item to the list... but there's not actually another issue.

Comment: Here on Meta, we close questions as dominates duplicates if the same report has been filed in the past, and hasn't been fixed yet. This is similar to closing issues as duplicates on open source issue trackers.