# Traffic is "0 visits/day" in EOS.IO beta site

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-analytics

There was an [issue reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/312043) early, it was completed for all the sites except [EOS.IO beta](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/) site.

For the EOS.IO site, still I can see the **0 visitors/day** in the site stats section, Area 51 and "Stack Exchange - All sites" page.

Screenshot for [site's](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/) stats section:

> [image: Stats]

Screenshot for [EOS.IO Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio) page:

> [image: Area 51]

Screenshot for [Stack Exchange - All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) page:

> [image: All sites traffic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking this as completed, but it's demonstrated to be kinda weird, so this is a note to our future selves to *not* close similar reports of this as a duplicate of this one, but rather make sure this one gets linked.

IOW: I can't find anything to blame for this getting fixed :) So it was either 'one of those things' or one of *those* things, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I remember this! Long story short, the site had a wrong Google Analytics property id specified in the site settings, so nothing was getting tracked. Dean fixed it up back in September. I definitely wouldn't close new reports of similar issues as a duplicate of this one as it was rather a one-off.

Answer (score 1):

Now for the EOS.IO site, the **visitors/day** value is displaying correctly in the site stats section, Area 51 and "Stack Exchange - All sites" page.

Screenshot for [site's](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/) stats section:

> [image: Stat]

Screenshot for [EOS.IO Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio) page:

> [image: Area 51]

Screenshot for [Stack Exchange - All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) page:

> [image: Stack Exchange]