# Is Site Traffic Data Gone for Good After Fixing Previous Bug?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, site-analytics

There was a previous bug affecting site traffic statistics showing -zero- for months ([Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51)). This has been fixed in that it is now graphing the data.

It appears that previous data may be lost? The graphs below are from https://engineering.stackexchange.com. I don't have access to any other sites' graphs to see if they are showing similar results.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I talked to Dean about this... It's not *lost*, but... Getting it back into the system is gonna be a lot of work. Unfortunately, work we don't have the time for.

If, at some point, we can spare the time to figure out how to merge it in... We'll do so. Otherwise, it probably *will* end up lost eventually. Either way, by then we should have plenty of new data.

Comment: Any update on this? Still really busy? Even having two different views (old data and new data) would be good.