# Why is the traffic history prior to February 2018 missing on the site analytics page here on Meta.SE?

Tags: support, statistics, traffic, site-analytics

On the site analytics page here on Meta.SE (https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics - requires 25k+ rep on this site), it seems that the traffic statistics history from prior to February 2018 is missing:

> [image: Graph history before February 2018 is zero]

(The graph omits the year from being displayed, but it's displayed on hover, and I've added it with the usual red freehand <s>circles</s>.)

Looking at the CSV of this graph, it looks like the first day to have any traffic statistics was February 6, 2018, but the numbers from that date are *extremely* low compared to the rest of the dates after that. It seems that traffic only began to be tracked in the late hours of that day.

Why is all traffic data on this site prior to the late hours of February 6, 2018 missing?

This is not addressed by [Why is half of the traffic history missing on /site-analytics on Medical Sciences?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357730/why-is-half-of-the-traffic-history-missing-on-site-analytics-on-medical-science), as in that case, the answer turned out to be the fact that the site had changed its domain name (in September 2018, a whole different month from the one here). This site has had a change of domain name, but that took place all the way in April 2014. This is also not addressed by [Traffic (views, visits) is not correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/377214), as that took place in July 2018 and affected *future* data, not *past* data. What happened in February 2018 that caused all data from then to be missing?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357730/why-is-half-of-the-traffic-history-missing-on-site-analytics-on-medical-science).  Or not?

Comment: @Ollie No, as I said in the last paragraph, that one's a different cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was asked and answered at the time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314609/282289

> I talked to Dean about this... It's not lost, but... Getting it back into the system is gonna be a lot of work. Unfortunately, work we don't have the time for.

> If, at some point, we can spare the time to figure out how to merge it in... We'll do so. Otherwise, it probably will end up lost eventually. Either way, by then we should have plenty of new data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be network-wide, as [Jon Ericson has pointed out in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash/161891?noredirect=1#comment1196163_161891) (maybe there's some site that has analytics data from before February 2018, but we know that at least Meta.SE and Biblical Hermeneutics don't have data before 2018).