# What's happened to the site statistics on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, statistics, site-analytics

The visits and views on Stack Overflow have vanished before January 2018.

What's happened to them? Are we going to have them restored?

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange is affected as well. I'm not sure but it *could* be related to changes they made [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989/295232).