# Why is half of the traffic history missing on /site-analytics on Medical Sciences?

Tags: support, statistics, traffic, site-analytics

I see on https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics

[image]

Why is half of the traffic history missing (last graph)?

I exported the CSV and all values before 2018-09-02 are 0.

Comment: [Related question about Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357739/why-is-the-traffic-history-prior-to-february-2018-missing-on-the-site-analytics), though that appears to be a different cause.

Answer (score 6):

This coincides with the [Site Name Change & Scope Redefinition](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/site-name-change-scope-redefinition), where the site's domain changed from `health.stackexchange.com` to `medicalsciences.stackexchange.com`. Of course I can't be 100% sure, but it's too close to ignore.

Note that there were [some problems with Google Analytics in 2018 which affected all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/295232) but those were solved in July 2018 already, so if you're seeing problems starting from September that year, this is a red herring.

Comment: Good catch, this raises suspicion indeed